# Embed web page into web view

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm building a smartphone app with cordova. My goal is to display a remote web page within the app, providing an additional footer that allows the user to switch between the web page and other content (e.g. configuration).

Unfortunately iframes aren't an option because of https and different behavior on the platforms. Using InAppBrowser doesn't let me display the footer (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3397).

The only possibility I see, is to build a completely native app for each platform and embed the webview by hand. Is there an alternative way using cordova or another cross-platform framework?

Comment: you can use cordova and create your own plugin based on the inAppBrowser but where you don't display it full screen

Answer (score 0):

ChildBrowser will do the wonder.
https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser

Comment: Seems to me like ChildBrowser is just the ancestor of inappbrowser: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_childbrowser_plugin_deprecating_use_inappbrowser.